# Calling MSSQL stored procedure from SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

It does not seem like SqlAlchemy supports calling stored procedures. Did anybody find a workaround for this that works with SQL Server?

Sample procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE list_lock_set @name varchar (5), @requester varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO list_lock (name, requester, acquired) values (@name, @requester, GETDATE())
    RETURN 0    
END
GO
```

This works:

```
import pyodbc
dbh = pyodbc.connect(driver=''{SQL Server}'', server=srv, database=db, uid=uid, pwd=pwd)
dbc = dbh.cursor()
dbc.execute("list_lock_set ?, ?", ['bbc', 'pyodbc'])
dbc.commit()
```

This does not produce an error but also but does not work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://usr:passw@srv/db?driver=SQL Server', echo=True)
engine.execute("list_lock_set ?, ?", ['bbc', 'sqlalchemy'])
```

Thank you.

**EDIT: It appears the best solution is to fish out pyodbc cursor from the engine:**

```
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
cursor.execute("list_lock_set ?, ?", ['bbc', 'using cursor'])
cursor.commit()
```

I can also obtain pyodbc Connection:

```
engine.raw_connection().connection
```

and set `autocommit=True`, but that might interfere with engine logic. Many thanks to @Batman.

Comment: Would dbc.execute("EXEC list_lock_set ?, ?", ['bbc', 'pyodbc']) work?

Comment: @Ross Bush just tried it again to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember this giving me grief before too. From memory either `session.execute()` or `connection.execute()` worked for me. There's also a `callproc()` method, which is probably the right way to go. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html

Also, I've had issues in the past with MSSQL which seemed to be due to something asynchronous happening where the method was returning before the procedure was finished, which resulted in unpredictable results on the database. I found that putting a `time.sleep(1)` (or whatever the appropriate number is) right after the call fixed this.

Comment: Thanks, engine.raw_connection().cursor() gets the underlying pyodbc cursor, on which I can do things directly.

Comment: Hi @Batman, did u ever figure out what was going on with the asynchronous behaviour you were experiencing? I'm getting something similiar to this and can't track down the root cause.

Comment: Not satisfactorily. It was definitely an issue with the procedure not having finished, but other that putting in a `time.sleep` I never found a solution.

Comment: pyodbc does not currently implement the optional .callproc method. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

Comment: @RogerThomas the fix for me was to put SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of every piece of SQL I execute via SQLAlchemy. As soon as MSSQL returns any kind of result it considers the query complete. Messages showing rows effected are included in this. NOCOUNT ON stops MSSQL from returning these messages.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Oh man.... I forgot about this. Thank you for the reminder!!!

Answer (score 14):

To have it working in sqlalchemy I managed to do it this way:

> ```
> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
> engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://usr:passw@srv/db?driver=SQL Server', echo=True)
> with engine.begin() as conn:
>     conn.execute("exec dbo.your_proc")
> ```

Comment: engine.begin/( is the key here. It starts a new transaction and commits it when the with block ends. I had problems with an sp that did delete/insert that never got persisten due to the engine not committing. So it has to be explicit like this.

Comment: This comes up every single time I have to work on calling procs after not doing so for a while from sql alchemy. The huge mistake that leads me chasing what the heck is going on is I forget to  SET NOCOUNT ON within the stored procedure. Not setting will cause the proc to return early doing nothing. Hope that helps anyone new or otherwise. Also calling "exec some_usp" within execute on the connection object is redundant but probably force of habit.

Comment: engine.begin() was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Even I was facing the same issue. SQLAlchemy was executing the procedure but no actions were happening.

So I tweaked it by adding connection.execute("exec <Procedure_name>")

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @MATEITA LUCIAN:

**Add input parameters to the stored procedure**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://usr:passw@srv/db?driver=SQLServer', echo=True)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute('EXEC dbo.your_proc @textinput_param = "sometext", @intinput_param = 4')
```

For those that aren't sure about how or what to refer to with the '....//usr:passw@srv/db?driver=SQL server', echo=True... part of creating the engine I would suggest reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) and choosing Option 1 - Provide a DSN.

**Retrieve output from the stored procedure**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://usr:passw@srv/db?driver=SQLServer', echo=True)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute('EXEC dbo.your_proc @textinput_param = "sometext", @intinput_param = 4')
    for row in result:
        print('text_output: %s \t int_output: %d' % (row['text_field'], row['int_field']))
```